# PHP mail function not working..with client side validation

Tags: php, jquery, email, validation, sendmail

Can't get those 3 scripts to play nicely. Trying to get this mail function working and sending mails. Ive removed the sensitive info and replaced it with generic terms. I also ahve another php mail function that uses preg_match and other validation methods however it wasn't working so i decided to remove that till it works then try to add the validation server side again..

I'm not that good at PHP but i'm detemiined to wrap my head around this so any help would be appreciated.

I usually test all this on my wamp but there is a live dev server @ marinetechegypt.com/contact.php/  it might not be up to date tho.

Here are the contents of all the related files.

**HTML form (contact.php)**

```
            <div class="col one-half">
            <h3> Send us an Email </h3>
                <div class="ajax_message"></div>
                <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="php-mailer.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="login" />
                    <p>
                        <label for="fname"> Your Name <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="input-short" id="fname" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
                        <?php if(isset($errName1)) echo $errName1; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email"> Your Email <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="input-long" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                        <?php if(isset($errEmail)) echo $errEmail; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label> Subject </label>
                        <input name="subject" type="text"  id="subject" class="input-short" placeholder="Subject"/>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="message"> Your Message <span class="required"> * </span> </label>
                        <textarea name="message" class="textarea-message" id="textarea" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                        <?php if(isset($errMessage)) echo $errMessage; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button small grey contact-submit" /></p> 
            </form>
            <div class="error-container" style="display:none;"> Please fill the above required fields correctly! </div>
        </div>
```

**php-mailer.php file:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $to = "RecipientEmailInbox";
       $subject = $_POST['subject'];
       $first_name_field = $_POST['fname'];
       $email_field = $_POST['email'];
       $message = $_POST['textarea'];
       $message = "
        Name: $first_name_field
        Email: $email_field
        Message: $message";
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: <RecipientEmailInbox>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= '[From] <SenderEmailInbox>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
include("OnCompleteURL");
ini_set("sendmail_from","EmailHeaderFrom");
ini_set("SMTP","SMTPAddress");
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
         } else {
                 echo "Error phpmailer";
          }
?>
```

**JS Client Side Validation**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
  return this.optional(element) || value != param;
}, "Please choose a value!");


$(".contact-form").each(function(){
    $container = $(this).next("div.error-container");
    //Validate Starts
    $(this).validate({
        onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
        errorContainer: $container,
        rules:{
          fname:{required:true,minlength:3,notEqual:'Your Full Name'},
          email:{required:true,email:true,notEqual:'Your Email'},
          subject:{notEqual:'Subject'},
          message:{notEqual:'Your Message'}

          ,message:{required:true,minlength:10}
        }
    });//Validate End

    //Submit Starts        
    $(this).submit(function(e){
        $frm = $(this);
        $name = $frm.find('*[name=fname]').val();
        $email = $frm.find('*[name=email]').val();
        $subject = $frm.find('*[name=subject]').val();
        $message = $frm.find('*[name=message]').val();

        if($frm.find('*[name=fname]').is('.valid') && $frm.find('*[name=email]').is('.valid')) {
            var action = $frm.attr('action');
            $frm.find('*[name=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('');

            $frm.prev(".ajax_message").slideUp(750, function () {
                $ajax_container = $(this);
                $ajax_container.hide();

                $.post(action, {
                    name: $name,
                    email: $email,
                    subject: $subject,
                    message: $message
                    }, function (data) {
                        $ajax_container.html(data);
                        $ajax_container.slideDown('slow');
                        $frm.find('*[name=submit]').attr('disabled', '');
                        if (data.match('success') != null) $frm.slideUp('slow');
                    });
                });
        }
    e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

});

Comment: What's the question? What's not working?

Comment: If you're testing on WAMP, then the mail functions might not work since you probably don't have a mail server set up locally. Where are you testing this?

Comment: Do you get a error or something ?

Comment: Where is the error and what is the error???

Comment: uploaded everything to server to see if its a WAMP config issue.. Still the front-end validation works like a charm however the email is still not sent to my inbox. I get the "Error php mailer". Which signifies to me the problem lies in php-mailer.php.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really doing anything with the ini_set functions, you need to put valid emails and valid data into it:

```
ini_set('SMTP' , 'smtp.yoursite.com');
ini_set('smtp_port' , '25');
ini_set('username' , 'example@example.com');
ini_set('password' , 'password');
ini_set('sendmail_from' , 'example@example.com');
```

Also, it doesn't make sense that you send the email BEFORE you set these settings.

You're actually doing the mail twice, before and after the settings. Define the settings and THEN send the email.

By the way,

```
this
won't
get a new line
```

You have to add \n into the text, unless you use a wrapper that can handle this operation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip i removed the extra mail() function and added the ini_set the code then the mail() function. Does the syntax look correct? Can u clarify where i'm missing the /n for the new lines ? you can see everthing in action @ marinetechegypt.com/contact.php